# How do I center my img tag inside picture tag vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to align my image vertically by margin:auto 0, but it is not woking. How can I fix this?

```
<header>
  <h1>About me</h1>
  <div>
    <picture>
      <img src=" images/images.png" alt="About me img" height="120" width="190">
    </picture>
    <p class="article">content</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
@media(min-width:600px) {
  div {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
  }

  img {
    margin: auto 0;
  }
```

if I do

```
picture {
  padding: auto 0;
}
```

it works, but I want to do this on img tag rather than picture tag in case the browser doesn't support picture tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply the flex property to picture

```css
#a1{
display:flex;
width:90vw;
height:50vw;
border:1px solid black;
align-items:center;
}

 #a2{
 display:block;
 margin: auto 0 ;
 width:10vw;
 height:10vh;
 border:1px solid red;
 
 }
```

```html
<div id='a1'>
<picture id='a1'>
      <img  id='a2'  src=" images/images.png" alt="" height="120" width="190">
 </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not center it vertically.

Comment: the red box shows that the image IS vertically centered.  Do you mean horizontally?

Comment: Sorry I mean I added this code to my css file but it did not work.